# How to find duplicates in a std::vector<strings> and return a std::list of them sorted alphabetically without duplicates in that resulting list

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class called Wordd, that has a member word_ which is a std::list

I am trying to find duplicates in that word_, and return an alphabetized list of them without duplicates in that returned list. So far my code compiles and links, but times out, probably due to some internal memory leakage, etc.

```
class FindDuplicatesFunctor
{
public:
    std::list<std::string> list;
    std::vector<std::string> word_;
    FindDuplicatesFunctor(std::vector<std::string> words): list(0), word_(words){};
    void operator()(std::string const& str)
    {

        if(std::count(words_.begin(), words_.end(), str) > 1 && std::count(list.begin(), list.end(), str) == 0)
        {
            list.push_back(str);
        }
        list.sort();

    }
};
std::list<string> Wordd::FindDuplicates() const
{
    FindDuplicatesFunctor cf(word_);
    return std::for_each(words_.begin(), words_.end(), cf).list;
}
```

Any ideas why it's not performing its tasks?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: std::sort, std::unique

Comment: Read more about the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: @sehe: surely you mistyped `std::unique_copy()`: he wants to create a list without duplicates (why a `std::list<std::string>` is beyond me as an `std::vector<std::string>` is the proper data structure but the algorithm would still be the same). Oddly enough, the argument is passed by value...

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yeah. It was a quick hint. See my answer though

Comment: @sehe: which, of course, doesn't answer the question why the original algorithm doesn't work ;)

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yeah. It's a shame, really :/

Comment: Is that the real code? what does `words_` inside `FindDuplicatesFunctor` refer to?, what are `word_` and `words_` in `FindDuplicates`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yeah, I need a list, because the function needs to return a list, because of other dependencies

Comment: Yeah, I still don't know why the original algorithm doesn't work :D

Comment: @user2624236: You are mixing up `word_` and `words_` in your code.

Comment: @JesseGood Yeah I am, it's typo

Comment: Ok, I tried @sehe's option, it's not that result that I was looking for though close; I want to take out all the words in the sentence that repeat themselves, if it has 2 "has" just put one has in the list, I am sorry I haven't made it clearer before

Comment: Remove duplicates function name is misleading, it is actually trying to return a list of words that are repeating in the sequence, but that result list only has one copy of each duplicate

Comment: std::sort, std::adjacent_find IIRC use with equal_to

Comment: @user2624236 So, I've updated my answer showing that approach. While intuitively right, `adjacent_find` here looks to be a little more creative than I'd normally want to write my code. So I added a second approach, also using standard algorithms. Hope you find it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort-unique-erase:

```
template<typename Container>
Container&& sort_unique_erase( Container&& c ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::sort( begin(c), end(c) );
  c.erase( std::unique( begin(c), end(c) ), end(c) );
  return std::forward<Container>(c);
}
```

works on any random access container that you can `erase` ranges from (`vector` and `deque` in `namespace std`).

Append then:

```
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1&& append( C1&& c1, C2&& c2 ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  c1.insert( end(c1), std::make_move_iterator( begin(c2) ), std::make_move_iterator( end(c2) ) );
  return std::forward<C1>(c1);
}
template<typename C1, typename C2>
C1&& append( C1&& c1, C2& c2 ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  c1.insert( end(c1), begin(c2), end(c2) );
  return std::forward<C1>(c1);
}
```

and tie them together:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> words = {"hello", "world", "my", "name", "is", "hello"};
  std::list<std::string> retval;
  append( retval, sort_unique_erase( std::move(words) ) );
  for( auto& str : retval ) {
    std::cout << str << "\n";
  }
}
```

however, using `std::list` is not advised: there are very few reasons to use it over `std::vector`, or in some rare cases `std::deque`.

Comment: Some nice idioms introduced there. I like using `append` free function  to hide the `make_move_iterator` business

Comment: @sehe In my own library, I have a `make_smart_move_begin`, which when passed an rvalue produces a `move_iterator(begin())`, and when passed an lvalue just calls `begin`. It violates the rules that you only move once, which is why I'm a bit leery of it, but it makes container-based algorithms much easier to write. I also have to detect for non-owning containers (because a `&&` reference to a view into a container does not imply moving) for that `smart_move` to be non-dangerous. The above code fails in that task: if you passed an rvalue C++14 `string_view`, it moves characters - noop, but rude.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit** In response to comment:

> <sup>*Remove duplicates function name is misleading, it is actually trying to return a list of words that are repeating in the sequence, but that result list only has one copy of each duplicate  – [user2624236](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2624236/user2624236) [10 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891059/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-stdvectorstrings-and-return-a-stdlist-of-them#comment26132135_17891059)*</sup>

I hinted `std::sort` + `std::adjacent_find(... std::equal_to<>)`. Here's the realization of that:

```
template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type> std::list<T> adjacent_search(C input)
{
    std::sort(begin(input), end(input));

    static const auto eq = std::equal_to<T>{};
    static const auto neq= std::not2(eq);

    std::list<T> dupes;

    auto end_streak = begin(input);
    auto dupe_at    = std::adjacent_find(end_streak, end(input), eq);

    for(auto end_streak=begin(input);
        (dupe_at = std::adjacent_find(end_streak, end(input), eq)) != end(input);
        end_streak = std::adjacent_find(dupe_at, end(input), neq))
    {
        dupes.insert(dupes.end(), *dupe_at);
    }

    return dupes;
}
```

This implementation has several nice properties, such as a linear scan and reasonable worst case behaviour (e.g. if input contains 1000 duplicates of a single value, it won't do 1001 useless searches).

However, the following (using a set) might be a lot simpler:

```
// simple, but horrific performance
template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type> std::list<T> simple(C const& input)
{
    std::set<T> dupes; // optimization, dupes.find(x) in O(log n)
    for (auto it = begin(input); it != end(input); ++it)
    {
        if ((end(dupes) == dupes.find(*it))) // optimize by reducing find() calls
         && (std::count(it, end(input), *it) > 1))
        {
            dupes.insert(dupes.end(), *it);
        }
    }

    return {begin(dupes), end(dupes)};
}
```

This will almost certainly perform better on smaller collections because there is less copying (except for the result). It could get rather bad worst case behaviour (for large inputs) because of the implicit linear search in `std::count`.

I'd suggest you return the `std::set<T>` directly, instead of copying it to the list.

Here's a test running **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3f0a23a045ba69f6029fa54014857957-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68)** showing both versions.

### Original answer

Now rather obsolete, because it didn't do what the OP wanted:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> input = { "unsorted", "containing", "optional", "unsorted", "duplicate", "duplicate", "values" };

    std::sort(begin(input), end(input));

    std::unique_copy(begin(input), end(input), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
containing duplicate optional unsorted values
```

See it live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f8cc78dbcce62ad276691b6541629a70-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68

Comment: If you are dead set on outputting to a list, use unique_copy as follows: `std::list<std::string> myList; std::unique_copy(begin(input),end(input),back_inserter(myList));`

Answer (score 1):

The `FindDuplicates()` function references `word_` and `words_`. It seems, these two names are meant to be the same, which one it should be, can't be determined from the code snippet.

The used algorithm is hideously slow, however: it requires `O(n * n)` time, potentially using many list operations which are even slower than vector operations. You surely want to use an approach along the lines of what sehe has posted (`std::sort()` followed by `std::unique_copy()`). If your set of values is really huge, you might want to consider to move to the set just once and keep a `std::set<std::string>` (or `std::unordered_set<std::string>`) or a a version using a `std::string const*` to determine if the value was already seen.

Comment: yeah it's a typo, meant word_